# Extra white space is showing at the bottom of my card title using Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to PHP and bootstrap. I am making a login form which was perfectly fine when I do not put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">` in my header.

But I can't just remove them from my header because I will need them at a later time because of some custom buttons, etc.

Take a look at this snippet below. As you can see, there is a white space when I already indicated the `mt-5`. Any idea what caused this and how to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```css
.index-banner {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 40, 0.5)), url(images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.primary-container {
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<?php require_once 'indexheader.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Leafnote | Register</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 m-auto">
        <div class="card bg-white mt-5">
          <div class="card-title text-black">
            <h5 class="text-center py-2 font-weight-bold">Register</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form action="process.php" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="passw" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="passw2" placeholder="Re-enter password" class="form-control mb-2">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3" name="register" class="pt-3">Register</button>

              <div class="text-center mt-3" style="font-size: 14px;">Already have an account?
                <a href="signup.php" class="alert-link">Login</a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where ever you feel there are extra padding add class "pb-0" and if any extra margin add class "mb-0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap Provide utilities classes which will be realy handy and reduce you extra css like adding padding or margin and many more..

where ever if you need to add or remove margin you can add class, same way you can work with padding

```
mb-0 , mb-10
```

You can get more info
[Bootstrap Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/)

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace is actually coming from a `margin-bottom` in your `card-title` class and `padding` from your `card-body` class which is defaultly available in bootstrap cards. Simply add this to your css file to overwrite the bootstrap css

```
.card-title {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.card-body {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to your stylesheet i.e. style.css**

```
.card-body{
    padding: 0 24px;
}

.card-title{
    margin:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of extra css as there are Bootstrap4 classes to remove your extra padding and margin. You can use `mb-0` to remove your `margin-bottom`. You can learn more about [Spacing in Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 m-auto">
        <div class="card bg-white mt-5">
          <div class="card-title text-black mb-0">
            <h5 class="text-center py-2 font-weight-bold mb-0">Register</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form action="process.php" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="passw" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="passw2" placeholder="Re-enter password" class="form-control mb-2">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3" name="register" class="pt-3">Register</button>
              <div class="text-center mt-3" style="font-size: 14px;">Already have an account?
                <a href="signup.php" class="alert-link">Login</a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
   </html>
```